# Gradle build in infinite state, but only in intelliJ debug mode

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea

When i try to build my multi-project in the debug mode of intelliJ, then i will end in an infinite build, means some threads (Execution Workers) will do their execution for an infinite time.

First of all, i looked into the Thread dump. I saw that every Thread, which end in the infinite state has the same stacktrace:

```
"Execution worker for ':' Thread 5" #51 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002918e800 nid=0x4104 runnable [0x000000002e93c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:224)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.rt.execution.ForkedDebuggerHelper.send(ForkedDebuggerHelper.java:48)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.rt.execution.ForkedDebuggerHelper.setupDebugger(ForkedDebuggerHelper.java:24)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.rt.execution.ForkedDebuggerHelper$setupDebugger$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115) 
...
```

[Full Trace Here](https://pastebin.com/6S9QetQh)

Furthermore i saw, that only Tasks of type `Test` or `JavaExec` are affected. Overall all tasks of type `JavaForkOptions`. And i saw, that i **didnt** get following message from IntelliJ for these threads, which ends up in the infinite state:

**Connected to the VM started by ':my-project:geb:test' (localhost:61041). Open the debugger session tab**

(For example).

Which task will end in an infinite state is non-deterministic and when i build the whole gradle build with the property `org.gradle.parallel=false`, then the build finish successfully. When i run this build without the debug mode, everything works fine.
I should mention, that this gradle script code will not be executed too for these infinite state threads:

```
gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
    if (task instanceof JavaForkOptions) {
        print('JvmArgs For Forking' + task.jvmArgs + ' -- in Task ' + task.getName() + '\n')
    }
}
```

I updated my Java 8 to java8_211 and i try to downgrade gradle from 5.4.1 to 4.10.3, but it doesnt work either.

EDIT: I reported this issue to JetBrains and they already have a ticket for it.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207748